# Temperature of Kerr black hole and conical singularity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, temperature, wick-rotation, black-hole-thermodynamics

For spherical static black holes, for example, the metric may take the form
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}+r^2d\Omega^2_d
\end{equation}
One can use conical singularity method to calculate its Hawking temperature: Firstly one analytically continue $t\rightarrow -i\tau$. Then by demanding the absence of conical singularity on $(\tau,r)$-plane, one get the periodicity of $\tau\sim\tau+\beta$, then the temperature $T=1/\beta=f'(r_h)/4\pi$.

My question is that could this procedure be generalized to stationary black holes, such as Kerr black hole, or rotating BTZ black hole?

Comment: Yes, it can be done and you can find it in several papers. There is probably something more specifically related with the temperature than this one, but for the Kerr BH I saw it explicitly here (section 2):

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9604118

Also, for the BTZ the following is a nice reference, covering a lot of topics (thermodynamics in the Euclidean version is discussed in section 6):

https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9506079